PIC32MX270F256D MIPS assembler code read to port value
I'm trying to display the port value using the Arduino IDE serial monitor, but it seems to jump around between some values, pressing a button or not.
it seems steady when no button is pressed, but various values are shown when a button is pressed until it settles. Even if you (Serial) print as DEC aside from HEX, BIN.
What is the MIPS assembler code to get the PORTB value and load this in a C++ variable?
i found this code to snoop around in the co-processor:
static unsigned int _Processor_cycle_count;
asm volatile("mfc0 %0,$9" : "=r" (_Processor_cycle_count));

Schematic:

code:
   bool pressed = false;
    bool pressed1 = false;
    bool pressed2 = false;
    bool pressed3 = false;
    
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      TRISAbits.TRISA10 = 0;  // onboard led.
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
      TRISAbits.TRISA8 = 1;  // onboard button.
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
    
      //  2 leds
      TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 0;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
      TRISAbits.TRISA1 = 0;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
    
      // 4 buttons.
      TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 1;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
      TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 1;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
      TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 1;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
      TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 1;
      asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop"); 

  //CNPDAbits.CNPDA0  // used
  //CNPDAbits.CNPDA1  // used
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA2 = 1;
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA3 = 1;
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA4 = 1;
  //CNPDAbits.CNPDA5 // not available.
  //CNPDAbits.CNPDA6 // not available.
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA7 = 1;
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA8 = 1;
  CNPDAbits.CNPDA9 = 1;
  //CNPDAbits.CNPDA10  // used
  
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB0  // used
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB1  // used
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB2  // used
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB3  // used
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB4 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB5 = 1;
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB6 // not available.
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB7 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB8 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB9 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB10 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB11 = 1;
  //CNPDBbits.CNPDB12 // not available.
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB13 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB14 = 1;
  CNPDBbits.CNPDB15 = 1;

  CNPDCbits.CNPDC0 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC1 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC2 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC3 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC4 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC5 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC6 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC7 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC8 = 1;
  CNPDCbits.CNPDC9 = 1;

    }
    
    static unsigned int _Processor_cycle_count;
    void loop() {
    
    LATAbits.LATA10 = ~LATAbits.LATA10;   // toggle onboard led
    delay(1000); 
    
      if ((!pressed) && (PORTBbits.RB0)) {
        Serial.println("The button 1 was pressed!\n\r");
        pressed = true;
      }
      else if ((pressed) && (!PORTBbits.RB0))
      {
        Serial.println("The button 1 was released!\n\r");
        pressed = false;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if ((!pressed1) && (PORTBbits.RB1)) {
        Serial.println("The button 2 was pressed!\n\r");
        pressed1 = true;
      }
      else if ((pressed1) && (!PORTBbits.RB1))
      {
        Serial.println("The button 2 was released!\n\r");
        pressed1 = false;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if ((!pressed2) && (PORTBbits.RB2)) {
        Serial.println("The button 3 was pressed!\n\r");
        pressed2 = true;
      }
      else if ((pressed2) && (!PORTBbits.RB2))
      {
        Serial.println("The button 3 was released!\n\r");
        pressed2 = false;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if ((!pressed3) && (PORTBbits.RB3)) {
        Serial.println("The button 4 was pressed!\n\r");
        pressed3 = true;
      }
      else if ((pressed3) && (!PORTBbits.RB3))
      {
        Serial.println("The button 4 was released!\n\r");
        pressed3 = false;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
    
      
    
      if (pressed) {
        asm("add $0, $0, $0"); // asm("nop");
        LATAbits.LATA1 = 1;
        Serial.println("The button 1 was presssssssssssssssssssed!\n\r");
      }
      else if(!pressed) {
        LATAbits.LATA1 = 0;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if (pressed1) {
        LATAbits.LATA1 = 1;
      }
      else {
        LATAbits.LATA1 = 0;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if (pressed2) {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
        Serial.println("The button 3 was presssssssssssssssssssed!\n\r");
      }
      else {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
      if (pressed3) {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
      }
      else {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
      }
      //-------------------------------------------------
    }

The button code came from the Microchip github.
update:
I have added the pull down internal pull down resistors, PORTC reads as 0 now, since there are no pins used on PORTC. but pressing button 1(RB0) and button 3(RB2) have slight erratic results on button press albeit being the same code although adapted.
update2:
after a bit of searching i found a few lines of assembler.
i found some blinking led code and adapted it.
But the number it's outputting looks like the address of port a register, because it's a larger number than port a has pins.
volatile uint32_t counter_timer = 0;

//asm("la   $s0, LATA \n"); // # Load the address mapped to the LATA control register
asm("la   $s0, PORTA \n");
asm("sw      $s0, %gp_rel(counter_timer)($gp) \n");

Serial.print("counter_timer: ");
Serial.println(counter_timer, DEC);


It would be very helpful if you could include at least a little diagram of what you have connected and how your ports are set up.  Surprise results reading from ports are almost always errors in wiring or configuring the port, occasionally the code for reading, and rarely the code for printing.

@jonathanjo, the Microchip Fubarino sits on a old breadboard, there are 2 additional leds on PORTA(0,1) and 4 additional buttons on PORTB (0,1,2,3), following the Fubarino schematic that's it. the configuration is done the same way as if i remove the Fubarino from the breadboard and run it bare bones.

@jonathanjo i have 4 times the same piece of code although "renamed" for the buttons, but 2 buttons react differently despite being the same code, one of the 2 leds flashes rather than staying on for a second. i have not set the internal pull up/down resistors.
adding "debug" code it seems to act normal, but physically it's not doing ...

Thanks , honestly it's much better if you draw a diagram, and it's really best if you edit the question with all this information.  You have been looking at the diagrams, circuits, datasheets: we're blind unless you give us links and put the diagrams in the question.

@jonathanjo I have added a schematic.

... now you just have to add the code.

@jonathanjo code added.

what is the behavior you see on the LEDs? Is it onboard LED blinks 1s on, 1s off; If button 1 is pressed, LED1 flashes on shortly every second; If button 2 is pressed, LED1 flashes off shortly every second; similarly for LED2 with buttons 3 and 4?

@BartvanIngenSchenau Button 2 (RB1) and button 4 (RB3) work as intended, every time the onboard leds (RA10) gets toggled one of leds  if pressed also lights up for a second or half second and later turn off. but button 1 an button 3 fail to work properly albeit being pretty much the same code.


Button 2 (RB1) and button 4 (RB3) work as intended, every time the onboard leds (RA10) gets toggled one of leds if pressed also lights up for a second or half second and later turn off. but button 1 an button 3 fail to work properly albeit being pretty much the same code.

The code for lighting a LED based on button 3 and 4 is

     if (pressed2) {
       LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
       Serial.println("The button 3 was presssssssssssssssssssed!\n\r");
     }
     else {
       LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
     }
     //-------------------------------------------------
     if (pressed3) {
       LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
     }
     else {
       LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
     }


The problem with this code occurs when pressed2 == true (button 3 pressed) and pressed3 == false (button 4 not pressed). In that case, the first if statement sets the LED on (LATAbits.TATA0 = 1), but the else of the second if statement immediately turns it off again (LATAbits.TATA0 = 1).
The only reason that you see the LED flash shortly is probably that the print statement takes enough time to let the LED actually light up.
If you want to have the LED light up when either button 3 or button 4 is pressed, you need to write the logic as
if (pressed2) {
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
  Serial.println("The button 3 was presssssssssssssssssssed!\n\r");
}
else if (pressed3) {
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;
}
else {
  LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;
}


Thnx, but no, now i reverted back from where i started, i disabled the code for button 2, 3 & 4. now i moved this piece of code for button 1 into a function, to not have the "IF ELSE" code blocks behind each other, but the same effect occurs, the led only flashes.

I want the MIPS assembler code to read the ports faster the Arduino IDE serial.println(..) can handle, so to speak off, it crops 0's.
